change default root component
using cli, I created Vue 2 project manually, Once created, I started to do tests.
I created a simple component testMe and in main.js I changed default code to let that new component be read as root component instead of App.vue.
I got [Vue warn]: Cannot find element: #test
testMe.vue
<template>
    <div id="test">
<h3>first component created</h3>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script>
  
  export default {
    name: 'testMe',
    components: {
    }
  }
  </script>

main.js
import Vue from 'vue'
import TestMe from './TestMe.vue'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  render: h => h(TestMe),
}).$mount('#test')```



This is chicken-egg situation. mount('#test') means #test should already exist at the time when you call it, i.e. on html page.

@EstusFlask then how to avoid/correct the situation ?

Mount to the selector specified in html file that loads the app. It's unclear what's your setup. Vue CLI? Then you already have a correct one by default

Your app should have an index.html. It is an element in this file that a Vue app typically mounts to.  What you've basically tried to do is have a Vue app mount to itself, which it obviously can't do.  If you used vue-cli to create the project, there would've been a <div id="app"> in the html file.  It is this div and id that the app originally mounted to.  Provided you didn't change the html file, you should mount to this div with mount('#app')

@yoduh @estus it worked when I used mount('#app') but what makes index.html a basic file ? why it is essential(why not  mount('#test'))?

see Vue docs.  a Vue app must be mounted somewhere inside an existing HTML file.  the element your app mounts to is not, nor can it be, part of your app.  your <div id="test"> element, being in a vue file, is part of your app.

@yoduh well I made an arbitrary test: I deleted the index.html file and set new Vue({   render: h => h(TestMe), }).$mount('#app') in main.js

at first I got Error: Child compilation failed:  Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/../../myProject/public/index.html' in '/../../myProject', but then when I closed visual studio then re-opened it, and npm run serve the UI was displayed

I don't understand how it worked ??? and to what '#app'is referring now in .$mount as the app element is not used nowhere ???

vue-cli uses html-webpack-plugin which I believe generates an html file for you if one isn't provided.  I imagine the vue-cli also automagically adds the #app div.  I would advise providing your own index.html file unless you have specific reason not to...

last question (I think xD), why is it necessary to add template in new Vue ? sample: new Vue({     template: '<next-board />',     vuetify,     i18n   }).$mount(#${appId});
also in this example there is no render fct

templates and render functions are two different ways you can create Vue components, either is fine to use.  https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/rendering-mechanism#templates-vs-render-functions

in index.html file you must have id=test not in testMe.vue
